# How would I establish a value for these watches?

Tags: time-keeping

The watches shown below do not work, but I'm trying to establish a value for each.  What kinds of historical sources and methods could I employ to determine if these are of historical or cultural value? If they have intrinsic value? If they are rare or unusual?

[image: pulsar]

[image: guess]

[image: hugo maxx]

[image: kenneth cole]

[image: timex]

[image: Oleg Cassini(?)]

Don't feel obliged to give an answer for all of these, but if you know anything about them, thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you need more info about a watch, feel free to ask, e.g. different angle pictures, features, serial number...

Comment: I don't think that H:SE should offer advice on what things are worth.  Your first line hints to the [scope parable](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3916/1401) I'm going offer a friendly revision to try to bring this question within scope for the site,  but I'm not optimistic. Both historians and merchants use historical sources and methods, but they are very different outcomes - many profession historians & academics have a code of conduct that prohibits them from offering an opinion in this context.

Comment: I am not an appraiser, but I'm pretty sure I bought one of those Timex Indiglos at a Sears back in the day for like $25. They were about the cheapest watches available. I used to go through crystals like nobody's business until realized a left-handed person should not wear their watch on that arm, so I didn't buy expensive watches.

Comment: I think Guess (is?)was a cheap popular fashion name (mostly known for jeans), and Pulsar also sold a lot of cheap watches.

Comment: Anybody know about the gold watch with the broken band? It has a chronograph too if that adds any worth at all..

Comment: Re. the gold watch - same brand "Oleg Cassini 31-853 DG Swiss Quartz Gold Tone Watch
Condition:Used Price: £9.22" (eBay) - that's around $12.72 US money. It has an intact wrist band by the look of it.

Comment: About 3 years ago I was at a charity bring-and-buy sale organised at my workplace and found a Tupperware box of old watches pretty much like these. All for £2 (around $2.76) each. I found one with a strap I could use on my existing watch and bought it. When I got it home I found it was a Sekonda 3101 which was on sale new at prices between £35 and £163. So I ditched the old watch. I still have the Sekonda.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - nice find! Sekonda's are great watches.

Comment: @ed.hank - I was so surprised that I contacted the organiser of the charity sale and offered 20 UK pounds, which is half the cheapest price I found online, and he said 'Don't worry about it, we've finished the accounts' I have to say that after two years the tiny gold bezel around the date window came loose and floated around under the glass but a guy in a watch repair booth in a market fixed it with a very tiny dab of superglue. Still, it's a nice watch.

Answer (score 6):

None of those watches are worth anything,  they are all quartz watches with generic movements.  Each one could be bought on ebay for less than 10 dollars.

Comment: Yes. "Hugo Maxx", "Kenneth Cole" are clothing and shoe manufacturers who branched out to sell watches... "Indiglo" was generic, low-end. "Guess" was a blue-jeans brand. The idea of having a watch face readable in darkness was useful, at the time. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett - exactly,  they are commonly referred to as "fashion watches" and are all pretty much the usual quartz movement just with a custom dial/hands made by each of the fashion houses. These are the watches you would buy at a Dillards, JC Penneys, or Target, not anything you would find at even a low end jewelry store.

Comment: The above goes for Oleg Cassiri (the "gold watch") too. That was another fashion designer, not a long-time watchmaker.